# How do we script so that Google Colab switches to another cell conditionally?

Tags: python, conditional-statements, google-colaboratory

I wanted to conditionally go to the next cell in Google Colab but I searched a bit but didn't find any way to do it.

```
print("1 or 2")

choice = input("")

if choice == "1":
 SCRIPT TO GO TO THE NEXT CELL

if choice == "2":
 print("2")
```

I also don't know of a way to label cells or something like that to easily switch over to that.

Comment: Why not just define a regular Python function, and then call that?

Comment: @GinoMempin But then I would have to run that cell and then call that function

Comment: Assuming there's way to switch to a different cell and programmatically run the code on that cell,... do you want the execution to go back to the original flow? What happens after running the code on the other cell?